# ¿Error: "The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"?

Tags: java, java-ee, io

Al ejecutar mi `Servlet` en **Eclipse** sale este error:

> "The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Para la aplicación web a ejecutar descargué `Apache-Tomcat 7.082` y lo incorporé a **Eclipse**, utilizo el Eclipse para `Java EE`, tengo el `JRE 8.151`.

**El código es el siguiente:**

```
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
* Servlet implementation class Mostrarunmensaje
*/
@WebServlet("/Mostrarunmensaje") 

public class Mostrarunmensaje extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */

    public Mostrarunmensaje() {
        super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head></head>");         
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<h1>Probando un servlet</h1>");
            for(int f=1;f<=10000;f++) {
               out.println(f);
               out.println(" - ");
            }
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");   
   }

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

}
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Para JavaEE, utiliza siempre el JDK, no el JRE. Dicho esto, no sé si el mensaje de error que te sale está relacionado (la clase ObjectOutputStream debería estar disponible también en el JRE).

Comment: Se que es una pregunta antigua pero me he encontré con un problema similar y la respuesta era actualizar Tomcat a la versión 8 o superior.